# Fill area between two points in python plotly

Tags: python, plotly

MRE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta

import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.01)
y = beta.pdf(x,2,5)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = x,
        y = y, 
    )
)
fig.show()
```

outputting
[image]

I want to fill between certain x points for example only between x in [0.2, 0.4], how can I do this using Plotly?

There are multiple questions and answers that fill whole area https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/ however cannot find answer that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code:

```
xx = np.arange(0.2, 0.4, 0.01)
yy = beta.pdf(xx,2,5)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = xx,
        y = yy, 
        fill = 'tozeroy'
    )
)
```

It gives:

[image: plot]